# hp vertica loading data issue

Tags: vertica

i am loading the data from text  in to vertica machine.

source

`*.csv`

target

`HP vertica database`

case:1

i am getting the text files as following

emp.txt

`empno,ename
 1,hari
 2,suri`

i am using the following process to load the data from the text file in to the vertica data base.

`copy scott.emp from 'emp.txt' 
 delimiter ',' null as '' skip 1 exceptions 'emp-error.log';`

it is loading the data successfully.

case:2

i am getting the text files

dept.txt

`"sno","sname"
"1",""
"2","suri __ is \ in uk
for 3.3 years"`

here also i am using the same process

`copy scott.dept from 'dept.txt' 
 delimiter ',' null as '' skip 1 exceptions 'emp-error.log;`

i am getting the error and data is not loading in to the target table

can any body help me how to load the data with out any errors.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really mention which error you are getting, however...

1. The second file uses quotes, so you'll want to set `enclosed by '"'` as a `COPY` option.  You can do this either at a column level or at a COPY statement level. If the quotes don't exist, `COPY` will pretend the whole column is quoted between the delimiters.
2. You're going to have problems with that last line.  `enclosed by` will allow you to have `delimiters` embedded in the quotes with no problems, but it does not allow `record terminators` to do so. You will have to preprocess the data to use `COPY`.

Your sample of data is too small for me to know for sure, but you could do something like add a semicolon to the end of each record (perhaps an `awk` script that looks for lines ending in `"` and tacking a `;` on the end).  Then use `record terminator ';'` on the `COPY` statement.